# Is it possible to declare a variable or constant of type Range?

Tags: ada

In Ada, we can take an array slice of any array, including a String, using a range. For example:

```
Name( 1 .. 3 )
```

We can also use a range in a for loop:

```
for I in 1 .. 10 loop
  --do something
end loop;
```

Or, we could iterate over an array as follows:

```
for I in X'Range loop
  X(I) := Function_Call;
end loop;
```

So, my current line of thinking is that a range in the form "1 .. 3" would be a Range literal, much like "3" is an integer literal, and X'Range is a property that returns the range of indexes in the array X (or similarly, some ordered type X, such as an integer or enum).

At the moment, I have some code that looks like this:

```
Name( 1 .. 3 )
```

I've always felt that magic numbers like that aren't a good idea, so I suppose I could define two constants:

```
Name_Prefix_Range_Begin : constant Integer := 1;
Name_Prefix_Range_End   : constant Integer := 3;
```

and then do this:

```
Name( Name_Prefix_Range_Begin .. Name_Prefix_Range_End )
```

However, I feel it would be much cleaner if it were possible to have a constant of type Range, and just write the following to get my array slice:

```
Name ( Name_Prefix_Range )
```

So, finally, after all that, is it possible to declare either a variable or constant that can store a range? How is it written? I have made guesses which don't compile, and have not been able to find any reference to this possibility.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Slices, and some other constructs that take ranges, can also take subtype names.

```
subtype Name_Prefix_Range is Integer range 1 .. 3;
```

and then you can use

```
Name (Name_Prefix_Range)
```

as well as

```
for I in Name_Prefix_Range loop
    ...
end loop;
```

In the language syntax, you can use a subtype name like this anywhere a `discrete_range` is needed.  The syntax of slices in RM 4.1.2 uses it.

Note that when I say "subtype name", this includes a "type name" defined by a `type` declaration; the name is technically a "first subtype" name.  So it's syntactically legal to say

```
Name (Integer)
```

but you will get a `Constraint_Error` at runtime.  More legitimate would be to do something like this:

```
for B in Boolean loop ...
for Ch in Character loop ...
```

Comment: A good answer, but it would be improved if it also directly answered the question: No, you can't declare a variable or constant that can store a range. (Well, you can define your own record type, but it won't be tied to the language use of `'Range` and so forth.)

Comment: Hmm, unfortunate. I did think about defining a type like that, but I thought it would be a bit of overkill, considering that I would never actually make a variable of that type.

Comment: @Ogre I don't think it would be overkill; I think that's a perfectly legitimate use of a subtype declaration.  (As another example, Ada has an `in` membership test operator where you can test that a value is `in` a subtype; it's certainly legitimate to define a subtype that you use only for that purpose, and never to declare a variable or other object.  So I think in your case, it's also fine.)